# How to calculate frequency of a dataframe or xlsx files?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe

```
How to calculate the frequency of each year and it should be daywise 
frequency of each year in a single excel or data frame?
library("readxl")
my_data <- read_excel("NE_hillM.xlsx")
str(my_data)

my_data = as.data.frame(my_data)
str(my_data)


f20 = as.data.frame(table(my_data$Year20))
f20$Var1 = as.Date(f20$Var1, "%Y%m%d")
f20$Var1 = format(f20$Var1, format="%m%d")
```

using the above code I can calculate the frequency of each column, but later
I am facing an issue to join the table as the dataset are uneven in
distribution[![I had tried to attach the link of a file, please help me][enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R3j-zTScsJH-F44A8LUlePN5MyXOdGa5/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You can extract month and date from each column count their frequency with `table` convert it into dataframe and `merge` all the lists together using `Reduce`.

```
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = 'Var1', all = TRUE), 
        lapply(names(my_data), function(x) {
              tab <- as.data.frame(table(substr(my_data[[x]], 1, 5)))
              names(tab)[2] <- x
              tab
})) -> result
result
```

Comment: sir, I want the day-wise frequency of each year.

Comment: even I tried to attach the excel file of the dataset. Please tell me how to calculate daywise frequency of each year in separate column in a single excel file

Comment: No, i am getting yearly frequency in some other format only. It doesn't working daywise frequency of each year

Comment: Can you show first few rows of how your expected output would look?

Comment: 16     NA     NA    866     NA     NA     NA
17     NA     NA     NA   1444     NA     NA
18     NA     NA     NA     NA   1151     NA
19     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    136

Comment: @shanti Please update your post with the expected output. The output is not clear from comments.